# Forcing a Windows service to fail

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2012

Whenever a specific Windows service fails I want to run a program I've created myself. However, I simply can't find a way to make it fail on purpose, so that I can actually test that everything works correctly.

Note that the service in question is not something I've written myself, so I can't make it fail programmatically from inside the code. I wouldn't, however, mind writing a program that can make a service fail.

Of course I would prefer just having a "Make service fail" button somewhere in services.msc ... ;)

The server I'm doing this on is running Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Did you try killing the service from Task Manager?

Comment: Yes - that just stops it normally according to services.msc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define "fail". If you want the process to end, just use [pskill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx) or a similar tool that can terminate a process elevated (as an admin).

Comment: Fail - as in making the service perform recovery actions defined in the service's setting. Will check out pskill and get back to you. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AndersHolmström Good to hear. Just remember that terminating services this way may cause problems if they do not clean up after themselves properly but that may be what you are testing, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use command line :

As an admin open the Windows Task Manager, in the Services tab find the service you want to test.  Right click the service and click on Go to process.  The selected process (if any) is the one corresponding to your service.  Kill this process to simulate a service failure.

Be aware that killing a process this way can lead to problems.